# Appwrite Database Encryption

Tags: database, security, appwrite

how does Appwrite handle database security? I am interested in data encryption.
Would the database be safe if someone gets access to the storage or would it be in plain text?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive data (e.g project/function variables, API keys, OAuth provider settings, etc) is encrypted using the `_APP_OPENSSL_KEY_V1` environment variable before being inserted into the database, so if someone gets access to the database, they will only see encrypted data.

We also quietly introduced the ability to [encrypt string attributes](https://appwrite.io/docs/references/cloud/server-dart/databases#createStringAttribute), but I'd like to try it more before announcing it more.

Comment: Okay. Is there a way to integrate features of mariadb and having appwrite still work with its feature set? MariaDb supports encryption if i am correct.
Is there also a possiblity to hos the mariadb database somewhere else? 
Senistive User data needs to be secure, what solutions does appwrite have for achieving that?

Comment: It depends on the feature. If it's transparent to application logic, then it's probably fine.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter where mariadb is. Appwrite just needs to be able to connect to the database.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by securing the data. As I said, you can encrypt string attributes. Otherwise, most of the time, it's the usual steps of locking down a database server.